# storing text to string from a file that contains spaces

Tags: c++

So I've been doing algorithms in C++ for about 3 months now as a hobby. I've never had a problem I couldn't solve by googleing up until now. I'm trying to read from a text file that will be converted into a hash table, but when i try and capture the data from a file it ends at a space. here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ifstream file("this.hash");
    file >> noskipws;

    string thing;
    file >> thing;
    cout << thing << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware of the noskipws flag i just don't know how to properly implement it

Comment: `noskipws` just means that the preceding whitespace will be included, so for example, `  hello` will be read as `  hello`, not `hello`. It doesn't do anything about reading `hello fred`. (that didn't format but hopefully you get the idea)

Comment: actually, if reading a string stops at whitespace then you'll probably find that setting `noskipws` makes it read nothing at all if it begins with whitespace, because it will immediately find a terminating character.

Comment: How do you want to load the text file? A line at a time? Try `getline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best tool for what you're trying to do is `get`, `getline` or `read`. Now those all use `char` buffers rather than `std::string`s, so need a bit more thought, but they're quite straightforward really. (edit: `std::getline( file, string )`, as pointed out by Dietmar Kühl, uses c++ strings rather than character buffers, so I would actually recommend that. Then you won't need to worry about maximum line lengths)

Here's an example which will loop through the entire file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    char buffer[1024]; // line length is limited to 1023 bytes

    std::ifstream file( "this.hash" );

    while( file.good( ) ) {
        file.getline( buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
        std::string line( buffer ); // convert to c++ string for convenience
        // do something with the line
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(note that line length is limited to 1023 bytes, and if a line is longer it will be broken into 2 reads. When it's a true newline, you'll see a `\n` character at the end of the string)

Of course, if you a maximum length for your file in advance, you can just set the buffer accordingly and do away with the loop. If the buffer needs to be very big (more than a couple of kilobytes), you should probably use `new char[size]` and `delete[]` instead of the static array, to avoid stack overflows.

and here's a reference page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Answer (score 3):

When using the formatted input operator for `std::string` it always stops at what the stream considers to be whitespace. Using the `std::locale`'s character classification facet `std::ctype<char>` you can redefine what space means. It's a bit involved, though.

If you want to read up to a specific separator, you can use `std::getline()`, possibly specifying the separator you are interested in, e.g.:

```
std::string value;
if (std::getline(in, value, ',')) { ... }
```

reads character until it finds a comma or the end of the file is reached and stores the characters up to the separator in `value`.

If you just want to read the entire file, one way to do is to use

```
std::ifstream in(file.c_str());
std::string   all((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: thank you for the `std::getline` delimiter parameter, did not realize that was an extra parameter